# No matching function for call to 'currency::currency()'

Tags: c++, constructor

I don't know what this error means:

When ever I compile it, it gives me that error :: means scope resolution but I still don't understand what those `Classname::classname()` means.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class currency
{
 int rupee,paisa;
 public:
 currency(int r, int p)
 {
    rupee=r;
    paisa=p;
 }
 void display()
 {
    cout<<"\nCurrency = Rs. "<<rupee<<"."<<paisa;
 }
 friend currency AddCurrency(currency,currency);
};

currency AddCurrency(currency,currency);

int main()
{  
 currency c1(5,50);
 c1.display();
 currency c2(94,49);
 c2.display();
 currency c3=AddCurrency(c1,c2);
 c3.display();

 getch();
 return 0;
}

currency AddCurrency(currency a,currency b)
{
    currency c;
    c.rupee=a.rupee+b.rupee;
    c.paisa=a.paisa+b.paisa;
    return c;
}
```

Comment: You code compiles for me but does not link.  Where is the implementation of `AddCurrency`?

Comment: There is no default constructor for `currency`. Replace `currency c;` with `currency c(1,2);` for example. What is your platform/OS/Compiler`?

Comment: 'currency currency::AddCurrency(currency, currency)' cannot be overloaded -it says

im new to this thing so dont know much but i m using win 7 and it says compiler is unknown xD

Comment: @PaulSanders what compiler do you use? I cannot compile the [OP's code](https://www.ideone.com/H8SOWn). The OP's code does contain the implementation of `AddCurrency`.

Comment: Using CodeBlocks software

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sorry, I missed the implementation of AddCurrency there. Apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your user defined constructor `currency::currency(int r, int p)` inhibits the compiler from synthesizing a default constructor.

If you are using C++11 or later, you can tell the compiler that you do want a default constructor to be synthesized:

```
currency() = default;
```

Alternatively you can write your own default constructor.

Full details can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor).

Comment: Question i added "currency () {}" after 7th and before 8th line of my code and it worked just like "currency() = default;" did what dose "currency () {}" < means ??

Comment: @StupidHuman `currency () {}` is simply an empty constructor. This is very basic C++ knowledge, it's time to open your C++ text book.

Comment: It's a default constructor (i.e., one that can be called without any arguments). It would be safer to initialize your members, like `currency() : rupee(), paisa() {}`

Comment: @Jabberwocky more specifically its a default constructor (it can be called with no arguments), with no [*member initializer list*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) (there is no `: rupee(...), paisa(...)`) and an empty body (it does nothing after initialising the members)

Comment: @StupidHuman in this situation `currency () {}` is equivalent to `currency () = default`

Comment: Thanks Everyone :)